# Network error when trying to view a contribution, caused by "Expected one PriceSet but found 25"

Tags: webform-civicrm, contributions

I am using CiviCRM 4.7.15 and the latest version of Drupal 7. I am experiencing a 'Network Error - Unable to reach the server' when I try to view a contribution in the contact record. I have followed the suggestions in the forum post by Coleman Watts entitled 'Troublshooting popups, autocompletes, or other javascript problems' without having resolved the problem

What happens:

- I have created a civicrm webform which contains a single contact to allow the contact to renew their membership. This appears to function correctly insofar as it updates the membership record and creates a contribution attached to the contact and the membership record.
- I then logout, login as admin user, go to the relevant contact record and select the contributions tab. If I try to edit the contribution it displays correctly. However if I try to view the contribution I get the Network Error.
- I can perform this same set of steps for at least two other users on this particular webform without incurring the same issue.

I have attached below the error details for the situation which fails.

```
There was a CiviCRM error at The Harlequin Club, Incorporated.
```

Date: 2017-01-25T13:05:57+11:00

***ERROR***

```
message:            Expected one PriceSet but found 25
code:
exception:          CiviCRM_API3_Exception Object
(
    [extraParams:CiviCRM_API3_Exception:private] => Array
        (
            [count] => 25
            [is_error] => 1
            [error_message] => Expected one PriceSet but found 25
            [error_code] => undefined
        )

    [message:protected] => Expected one PriceSet but found 25
    [string:Exception:private] =>
    [code:protected] => 0
    [file:protected] => /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/api/api.php
    [line:protected] => 45
    [trace:Exception:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/Form/ContributionView.php
                    [line] => 158
                    [function] => civicrm_api3
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => PriceSet
                            [1] => getsingle
                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] =>
                                    [return] => is_quick_config, id
                                )

                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php
                    [line] => 531
                    [function] => preProcess
                    [class] => CRM_Contribute_Form_ContributionView
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Display.php
                    [line] => 92
                    [function] => buildForm
                    [class] => CRM_Core_Form
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
              ...
```

***LAST ERROR***

***LOGGED IN USER***

```
contact_id:         1
display_name:       Mr. Harlequin Webmaster
email_id:           2
email:              webmaster@quins.com.au
id:                 1

REMOTE_ADDR: 1.136.96.213
HTTP_USER_AGENT: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.112 Safari/537.36


***SERVER***
REDIRECT_protossl:  s
REDIRECT_HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:
REDIRECT_HTTPS:     on
REDIRECT_SSL_TLS_SNI:www.quins.com.au
REDIRECT_STATUS:    200
protossl:           s
HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:
HTTPS:              on
SSL_TLS_SNI:        www.quins.com.au
SSL_SERVER_S_DN_OU: Domain Control Validated
SSL_SERVER_S_DN_CN: *.quins.com.au
SSL_SERVER_I_DN_C:  BE
SSL_SERVER_I_DN_O:  GlobalSign nv-sa
SSL_SERVER_I_DN_CN: AlphaSSL CA - SHA256 - G2
SSL_VERSION_INTERFACE:mod_ssl/2.4.7
SSL_VERSION_LIBRARY:OpenSSL/1.0.1f
SSL_PROTOCOL:       TLSv1.2
SSL_SECURE_RENEG:   true
SSL_COMPRESS_METHOD:NULL
SSL_CIPHER:         ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
SSL_CIPHER_EXPORT:  false
SSL_CIPHER_USEKEYSIZE:128
SSL_CIPHER_ALGKEYSIZE:128
SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY:  NONE
SSL_SERVER_M_VERSION:3
SSL_SERVER_M_SERIAL:1121698500FC96BF666F1B30663DE1324AC8
SSL_SERVER_V_START: Jun 24 06:15:42 2015 GMT
SSL_SERVER_V_END:   Jun 24 06:15:42 2018 GMT
SSL_SERVER_S_DN:    CN=*.quins.com.au,OU=Domain Control Validated
SSL_SERVER_I_DN:    CN=AlphaSSL CA - SHA256 - G2,O=GlobalSign nv-sa,C=BE
SSL_SERVER_A_KEY:   rsaEncryption
SSL_SERVER_A_SIG:   sha256WithRSAEncryption
SSL_SESSION_ID:     f3a8f70a6aea5aa15c236bc37e1e701166071402a5356d67b3069294bd1f990b
SSL_SESSION_RESUMED:Resumed
HTTP_HOST:          www.quins.com.au
HTTP_CONNECTION:    keep-alive
HTTP_ACCEPT:        application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH:XMLHttpRequest
HTTP_USER_AGENT:    Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.112 Safari/537.36
HTTP_REFERER:       http://post.flyingenvelope.com/f/a/Ybra47iN3HGx_WwoNS9lIA~~/AABaNgA~/RgRaaTuHP0EIAKxD50iNdStXA3NwY1gEAAAAAFkGc2hhcmVkYQ5mbHlpbmdlbn    ZlbG9wZWANNTQuMjQ0LjQ4LjEzMEIKAAIHCIhYmGR2C1IWd2VibWFzdGVyQHF1aW5zLmNvbS5hdQlRBAAAAABEPGh0dHBzOi8vd3d3LnF1aW5zLmNvbS5hdS9jaXZpY3JtL2NvbnRhY3Qvdmlldz9yZ    XNldD0xJmNpZD04NEcCe30~    
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING:gz    ip, deflate, sdch    
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE:en    -US,en;q=0.8,en-AU;q=0.6,en-GB;q=0.4    
HTTP_COOKIE:        Dru    pal.tableDrag.showWeight=0; webform-    4580[1485308168]=1485308168; webform-4580[1485309881]=1485309881;     SSESS1a6aea6ec131844971    20f080e47a50a5=CDWCF1NwTZEVPOMhCqJw-    eyecyJdC2vGR5ul6s90_Fc; adaptive_image=1280; has_js=1    
PATH:               /us    r/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbi    n:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin    
SERVER_SIGNATURE:   <ad    dress>Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server a    t www.quins.com.au Po    rt 443</address>    

SERVER_SOFTWARE:    Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
SERVER_NAME:        www.quins.com.au
SERVER_ADDR:        172.31.15.76
SERVER_PORT:        443
REMOTE_ADDR:        1.136.96.213
DOCUMENT_ROOT:      /var/www/html
REQUEST_SCHEME:     https
CONTEXT_PREFIX:
CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT:/var/www/html
SERVER_ADMIN:       webmaster@quins.com.au
SCRIPT_FILENAME:    /var/www/html/index.php
REMOTE_PORT:        16143
REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING:reset=1&id=4189&cid=84&action=view&context=contribution&selectedChild=contribute&snippet=json
REDIRECT_URL:       /civicrm/contact/view/contribution
GATEWAY_INTERFACE:  CGI/1.1
SERVER_PROTOCOL:    HTTP/1.1
REQUEST_METHOD:     GET
QUERY_STRING:       reset=1&id=4189&cid=84&action=view&context=contribution&selectedChild=contribute&snippet=json
REQUEST_URI:        /civicrm/contact/view/contribution?reset=1&id=4189&cid=84&action=view&context=contribution&selectedChild=contribute&snippet=json
SCRIPT_NAME:        /index.php
PHP_SELF:           /index.php
REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT: 1485309956.761
REQUEST_TIME:       1485309956
```

***BACKTRACE***

```
#0 /var/www/html/sites/default/files/civicrm/extensions/ca.bidon.reporterror/reporterror.php(251): reporterror_civicrm_generatereport("The Harlequin     Club, Incorporated", (Array:3), NULL, (Array:0))    
#1 /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/C    ore/Error.php(439): reporterror_civicrm_handler((Array:3))    
#2 /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/C    ore/Invoke.php(55): CRM_Core_Error::handleUnhandledException(Object(CiviCRM_API3_Exception))    
#3 /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupa    l/civicrm.module(448): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:4))    
#4 [internal function](): civicrm_invoke("contac    t", "view", "contribution")    
#5 /var/www/html/includes/menu.inc(527): call_us    er_func_array("civicrm_invo    ke", (Array:3))    
#6 /var/www/html/index.php(20): menu_execute_active_handler()    
#7 {main}
```

***POST***

***FULL BACKTRACE***
**next call**

```
file:               /var/www/html/sites/default/files/civicrm/extensions/ca.bidon.reporterror/reporterror.php
line:               251
function:           reporterror_civicrm_generatereport
args:               Array
(
    [0] => The Harlequin Club, Incorporated
    [1] => Array
        (
            [message] => Expected one PriceSet but found 25
            [code] =>
            [exception] => CiviCRM_API3_Exception Object
                (
                    [extraParams:CiviCRM_API3_Exception:private] => Array
                        (
                            [count] => 25
                            [is_error] => 1
                            [error_message] => Expected one PriceSet but found 25
                            [error_code] => undefined
                        )

                    [message:protected] => Expected one PriceSet but found 25
                    [string:Exception:private] =>
                    [code:protected] => 0
                    [file:protected] => /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/api/api.php
                    [line:protected] => 45
                    [trace:Exception:private] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [file] => /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/Form/ContributionView.php
                                    [line] => 158
                                    [function] => civicrm_api3
                                    [args] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => PriceSet
                                            [1] => getsingle
                                            [2] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [id] =>
                                                    [return] => is_quick_config, id
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [file...
```

**next call**

```
file:               /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php
line:               439
function:           reporterror_civicrm_handler
args:               Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [message] => Expected one PriceSet but found 25
            [code] =>
            [exception] => CiviCRM_API3_Exception Object
                (
                    [extraParams:CiviCRM_API3_Exception:private] => Array
                        (
                            [count] => 25
                            [is_error] => 1
                            [error_message] => Expected one PriceSet but found 25
                            [error_code] => undefined
                        )

                    [message:protected] => Expected one PriceSet but found 25
                    [string:Exception:private] =>
                    [code:protected] => 0
                    [file:protected] => /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/api/api.php
                    [line:protected] => 45
                    [trace:Exception:private] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [file] => /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/Form/ContributionView.php
                                    [line] => 158
                                    [function] => civicrm_api3
                                    [args] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => PriceSet
                                            [1] => getsingle
                                            [2] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [id] =>
                                                    [return] => is_quick_config, id
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [file] => /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm...
```

**next call**

```
file:               /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php
line:               55
function:           handleUnhandledException
class:              CRM_Core_Error
type:               ::
args:               Array
(
    [0] => CiviCRM_API3_Exception Object
        (
            [extraParams:CiviCRM_API3_Exception:private] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 25
                    [is_error] => 1
                    [error_message] => Expected one PriceSet but found 25
                    [error_code] => undefined
                )

            [message:protected] => Expected one PriceSet but found 25
            [string:Exception:private] =>
            [code:protected] => 0
            [file:protected] => /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/api/api.php
            [line:protected] => 45
            [trace:Exception:private] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [file] => /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/Form/ContributionView.php
                            [line] => 158
                            [function] => civicrm_api3
                            [args] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => PriceSet
                                    [1] => getsingle
                                    [2] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] =>
                                            [return] => is_quick_config, id
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [file] => /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php
                            [line] => 531
                            [function] => preProcess
                            [class] => CRM_Contribute_Form_ContributionView
                            [type] => ->
                            [args] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [2] => ...
```

**next call**

```
 file:               /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module
 line:               448
 function:           invoke
 class:              CRM_Core_Invoke
 type:               ::
 args:               Array
 (
     [0] => Array
         (
             [0] => civicrm
             [1] => contact
             [2] => view
             [3] => contribution
         )

 )
```

**next call**

```
function:           civicrm_invoke
args:               Array
(
    [0] => contact
    [1] => view
    [2] => contribution
)
```

**next call**

```
file:               /var/www/html/includes/menu.inc
line:               527
function:           call_user_func_array
args:               Array
(
    [0] => civicrm_invoke
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => contact
            [1] => view
            [2] => contribution
        )

)
```

**next call**
    file:               /var/www/html/index.php
    line:               20
    function:           menu_execute_active_handler
    args:               Array
    (
    )

Martin Fuggle
1:20 PM (38 minutes ago)

to Site

```
There was a CiviCRM error at The Harlequin Club, Incorporated.
Date: 2017-01-25T13:20:31+11:00
SSL_SESSION_ID:     ea0aba40d7bbba6208e30995e64d1f67cf35193cf38c5775b89d086c1308098f
SSL_SESSION_RESUMED:Resumed
HTTP_HOST:          www.quins.com.au
HTTP_CONNECTION:    keep-alive
HTTP_ACCEPT:        application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH:XMLHttpRequest
HTTP_USER_AGENT:    Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.112 Safari/537.36
HTTP_REFERER:       http://post.flyingenvelope.com/f/a/RrIwh7O2i0LtT9ImrpKuaA~~/AABaNgA~/RgRaaT7xP0EIAmxDryS9WixXA3NwY1gEAAAAAFkGc2hhcmVkYQ5mbHlpbmdlbn    ZlbG9wZWANNTQuMjQ0LjQ4LjEzMEIKAAlxC4hYCTVrVVIWd2VibWFzdGVyQHF1aW5zLmNvbS5hdQlRBAAAAABEPGh0dHBzOi8vd3d3LnF1aW5zLmNvbS5hdS9jaXZpY3JtL2NvbnRhY3Qvdmlldz9yZ    XNldD0xJmNpZD04NEcCe30~    
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING:gz    ip, deflate, sdch    
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE:en    -US,en;q=0.8,en-AU;q=0.6,en-GB;q=0.4    
HTTP_COOKIE:        Dru    pal.tableDrag.showWeight=0; webform-    4580[1485308168]=1485308168; webform-4580[1485309881]=1485309881;     webform-4580[1485310058    ]=1485310058; webform-4580[148531010    4]=1485310104;     SSESS1a6aea6ec131844971    20f080e47a50a5=SbI-oLpmvbwaJSCa8w5vB    b9KbmHjvI3SfKOD    31CqbfM; adaptive_image=1280; has_js=1
PATH:               /us    r/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbi    n:/usr/bin:/sbi    n:/bin
SERVER_SIGNATURE:   <ad    dress>Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server a    t www.quins.com    .au Port 443</address>

SERVER_SOFTWARE:    Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
SERVER_NAME:        www.quins.com.au
SERVER_ADDR:        172.31.15.76
SERVER_PORT:        443
REMOTE_ADDR:        1.136.96.213
DOCUMENT_ROOT:      /var/www/html
REQUEST_SCHEME:     https
CONTEXT_PREFIX:
CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT:/var/www/html
SERVER_ADMIN:       webmaster@quins.com.au
SCRIPT_FILENAME:    /var/www/html/index.php
REMOTE_PORT:        5354
REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING:reset=1&id=4190&cid=84&action=view&context=membership&selectedChild=contribute&compId=23&compAction=4&snippet=json
REDIRECT_URL:       /civicrm/contact/view/contribution
GATEWAY_INTERFACE:  CGI/1.1
SERVER_PROTOCOL:    HTTP/1.1
REQUEST_METHOD:     GET
QUERY_STRING:       reset=1&id=4190&cid=84&action=view&context=membership&selectedChild=contribute&compId=23&compAction=4&snippet=json
REQUEST_URI:        /civicrm/contact/view/    contribution?reset=1&id=4190&cid=84&action    =view&context=membership&selectedChild=contribute&compId=23&compAction=4&snippet=json
SCRIPT_NAME:        /index.php    
PHP_SELF:           /index.php    
REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT: 1485310831    .199    
REQUEST_TIME:       1485310831
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I have this error also, from a very similar setup. It's due to the line items in CiviCRM not getting correctly created by CiviCRM Webform. I have been working around it with some sql that looks like this for me:

```
update civicrm_line_item set price_field_id = [something], price_field_value_id = [something], financial_type_id = [something] where entity_table = 'civicrm_contribution' and isnull(price_field_id) and label = '[something]' and unit_price = '[something]';
```

In other words - the good new is that there should be enough information in Civi to fix the price field id and price field value id, but it's an ugly work around at this point.

I posted an issue here:

https://www.drupal.org/node/2840851

and a tentative patch to fix the issue in the webform civicrm code, here:

https://www.drupal.org/node/2840851#comment-11906821